# Proving associative property of an infinite convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The wording of this question had confused me so much that I had to go to the solutions manual before even attempting the proof. After staring at it for an hour, utterly defeated, I gave in.

> Prove if an infinite series converges, then the associative property holds. Assume $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 + ...$ converges to a limit $L$ (i.e. the sequence of partial sums $(s_n) \to L$). Show that any regrouping of the terms
>
> $(a_1 + a_2 + ... a_{n_1}) + (a_{n_1 + 1} + ... + a_{n_2}) + (a_{n_2 + 1} + ... a_{n_3}) + ...$
>
> leads to a series that also converges to $L$.

This question seemed very...busy. I understand the principle, I initially had the idea to map each subsequence to an element $s_n$ to show that no matter how we order we still get the same sums somewhere. But this would've required some sort of combinatoric argument on the number of different orderings of parentheses which I followed and got lost. More to the point the "chapter theme" would seem to imply a combinatoric proof wouldnt be what he was looking for anyway. Checking the proof in the solutions manual:

Letting $s_n = a_1 + a_2 + ... + s_n$

We are given that $\lim s_n = L$.

Let's write:

$b_1 = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n_1}$

$b_2 = a_{n_1 + 1} + a_{n_1 + 2} ... a_{n_2}$

$.$

$.$

$.$

$b_m = a_{n_{m - 1} + 1} + ... + a_{n_m}$

and the claim is that the series $\sum_{m = 1}^\infty b_m$

To prove this, just observe that if $(t_m)$ is the sequence of partial sums for the regrouped series:

$t_m = b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_m$

$t_m = (a_1 + ... + a_{n_1}) + ... + (a_{n_{m - 1} + 1} + ... + a_{n_m}) = s_{n_m}$

which means that $(t_m)$ is a subsequence of $(s_n)$ and therefore converges to $L$ by theorem 2.5.2 (subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit).

Leaves me with a bunch of questions:

1. Why is $s_n$ recursive in his proof? Shouldn't it be $a_n$?
2. How does this prove in general *any* ordering without being combinatoric and/or inductive? It seems he only provided one ordering $(b_m)$.
3. What is the key observation here? The proof seems very busy and it's hard to pick out what I should know for future proofs so I dont have to run to the solution manual for help.

Comment: You use the word "ordering." It's not true that every different ordering of the terms gives the same sum. Infinite sums need not be commutative. But it's associative as long as you don't change the order.

Comment: For question 1, yes, where you have written $s_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+s_n$, it should be $s_n=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n$.

Comment: Also, to say what @Matt is saying in a different way, the associative law does not involve changing any orders. In its simplest form, $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$, you see that no order is being changed, just parentheses being moved around.